# passing pipeline parameter in column mapping

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

i am trying to configure a default value as my sourceID column.
my source is a FILe and my sink is a db table.
hence, i cant define the sourceID in sql query.

i created a parameter and defined the value.
intent to pass the parameter in the column mapping's dynamic content string.
however, i couldnt get the parameter value loaded into my table.

please advice if i made mistake in the dynamic content definition or there is better way to achieve the desired outcome.

```
    {
"type":"TabularTranslator",
"columnMappings":{
    "AS_OF_DATE":"AS_OF_DATE",
    "SECTOR_ID":"SECTOR_ID",
    "ASSET_GROUP":"ASSET_GROUP",
    "REGION":"REGION",
    "COUNTRY":"COUNTRY",    
    "FIELD":"FIELD",
    "SECTOR_FLAG":"SECTOR_FLAG",    
    "PRODUCT":"PRODUCT",
    "PERIODICITY":"PERIODICITY",
    "UNIT_CODE":"UNIT_CODE",
    "OPERATORSHIP":"OPERATORSHIP",
    "OPRNAME":"OPRNAME",
    "ACTUAL":"ACTUAL",
    "PLAN":"PLAN",
    "SOURCE_ID":"@{pipeline().parameters.sourceIDmpm}"


    }
}
```

Comment: hope to have some advice on this again.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically map column in copy activity, please define a parameter with type 'Object' in pipeline:

```
"parameters": {
"columnMapping": {
"type": "Object"
}
 }
```

and reference this parameter in copy activity like:

```
"translator": {
"value": "@pipeline().parameters.columnMapping",
"type": "Expression"
}
```

Please notice that you need to pass a JSON value to parameter. For example, I pass to the parameter

```
'columnMapping'.
{
"type": "TabularTranslator",
"columnMappings": {
"Prop_0": "Prop_0",
"Prop_1": "Prop_1", "Prop_2": "Prop_2"
}
}
```

For more details, you may refer the [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3e87a117-b3e8-4554-b3af-9434a15e9c66/how-to-do-a-dynamic-column-mapping-in-copy-activity?forum=AzureDataFactory) thread which addressing similar issue.

Hope this helps.